# iPhone Single Sign On

Tags: iphone, vpn, ios4, single-sign-on

Does anyone have a link to information regarding integrated, single-sign-on solutions for web apps for the iPhone/iPad and using one of the new VPN clients available in iOS 4?

With a typical intranet application I develop using ASP.NET for consumption with Firefox or IE, we use NTLM/Kerberos authentication, and the user's credentials are automatically supplied by the browser. Is there anything like this for iOS 4, especially now that we have VPN clients available?

Comment: Just to clarify, I'd like to see functionality similar to the "Use Integrated Windows Authentication" that's available out of the box in Internet Explorer for domain users when connecting into IIS. It leverages NTLM/Negotiate authentication.